# NSCFType keeps occurring, something is not being released?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, runtime-error, nsfilemanager

I'm attempting to delete files from the documents directory using a tableview/array combination.
For some reason, my `NSString` pointing to the Documents directory path is being converted to a `NSCFType` (which after some research, I understand is happening because a variable is not being released). Because of this, the application crashes at the line

```
NSString *lastPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:temp];
```

claiming that `NSCFType` cannot recognize the method `stringByAppendingPathComponent`.

I would appreciate if someone could help me out (I hope I have explained this clearly enough).

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView
commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle
 forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSString *temp = [directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(temp);

        NSString *lastPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:temp];


        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:lastPath error:nil];
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {

       paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

       documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       directoryContent = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil] retain];

//tableview handling below


}
```

Comment: post the code where you set documentsDirectory

Comment: Documentsdirectory is definitely being released somewhere.  Is it declared strong, or retained (ARC or MRC).

Comment: In the future, please put the code into your question here rather than off-site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that `documentsDirectory` is being set to an autoreleased object to fix that,

You either retain it

```
documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] retain];
```

Or you initialize it just before using it each time like this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);       
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lastPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:temp];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:lastPath error:nil];
```

My advice, dont add all these variable as instance variable, you dont need to, its better creating them whenever you need them

Comment: That's not initialization, that's the same thing as calling retain.

Comment: @CodaFi i meant not using them as instance variable, and decreasing their scope to function variables

Comment: If that iVar decreases scope, he loses the possibility of keeping track of it, and referencing it later, which defeats the purpose of retain.

Comment: do you really need an iVar for documentsDirectory?

Comment: Thank you both, I'll research further into it to make sure I don't run into any issues again.

Comment: Why not?  For all anybody cares, that thing could be a Class.  What he needs is proper variable initialization.

Comment: yes ok, but having a variable for documentDir and another var for path and another one for documentContent will result in bad design, soon enough his class will have 300 variables

Comment: @codafi "documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];" this assigned an autoreleased object wich seems that it has been released before this "NSString *lastPath = [documentsDirectory"